# rhythmbox won't play certain songs

Tags: rhythmbox

For the most part Rhythmbox works fine. However, there is one song in my library that it refuses to play, or add to any playlist. VLC will take it, and Audacity will as well, but Rhythmbox will just exit silently. Running with -d yields a similar output to the other non-broken MP3s. For what it's worth, I'm running Rhythmbox 2.96 with Ubuntu 12.04 Help?

Comment: Could you explain in more details how you discovered what was the issue and how to solve it? You can answer your own question below, and mark it as accepted so people that might find in the same situation as you were know why is happening, and how to solve it.

Comment: I think there was some error in the MP3 file that caused it to fail. Opening it with Audacity and saving it removed the error, so now it works. Case closed or something.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of your mp3, open it in Audacity and make a tiny inessential edit in it, perhaps cutting a little bit of time off the blank space at the end of it, and then save your mp3 at a slightly higher bitrate. Select *File* -> *Export* and from the **Export File** window select *Options* -> *Specify MP3 Options* -> and then change the *Quality* settings to a slightly higher bitrate. When you Export the mp3, redo every entry in the **Edit Metadata** window to make sure that the metadata tags for your exported mp3 have been entered correctly.

Comment: The OP has indicated that this has worked - so I've undeleted it +1